# PHP Create Loop to handle unknown number of incoming POST data

Tags: php

I'm working with a web service that will be sending data via a POST request. I would usually handle this in the typical way, e.g.

```
$request->setField('attachment0', $_POST['attachment0']);
```

I need to expand this to handle multiple POST data that increment, e.g. pseudo code like this:

```
 $request->setField('attachment0', $_POST['attachment0']);
 $request->setField('attachment1', $_POST['attachment1']);
 $request->setField('attachment2', $_POST['attachment2']);
```

and so on. Rather than hardcode these and have 10 separate lines, I'd like to set a counter variable with the maximum possible, e.g. 10 then have a loop that increments as it goes, e.g.:

```
set counter to 1
if counter < 10
$request->setField('attachment($counterValue)', $_POST['attachment($counterValue)']);
finish when counter = 10
```

Is this possible with PHP - I'm fairly new to PHP so still learning the ropes here?

Comment: Will there always be 10?

Comment: You realise that attachments will be `$_FILES`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just use a [`for`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loop:

```
for( $i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++ )
{
  $request->setField("attachment$i", $_POST["attachment$i"]);
}
```

You can even make it fully dynamic (i.e. if you don't know how many to expect) using a `while` loop instead:

```
$i = 0;

while( isset($_POST["attachment$i"]) )
{
  $request->setField("attachment$i", $_POST["attachment$i"]);
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count(your_aaay_count); $i++ ){
  $request->setField("attachment$i", $_POST["attachment$i"]);
}
```

Hope this will work